# Connect to the strongest wifi AP in kde?

Tags: wireless-networking, kde

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04, which has KDE 4.13.2. At the moment, when ever I start up, or resume from suspend, KDE automatically connects to a previously used wireless network, but it does so in some unknown, and of the 3-4 known networks that are available to me, it seems to always pick one of the weakest ones. Most of the time, this means that I have to manually re-connect to the closest network.

Is there any way to force KDE network manager to automatically connect to the strongest known wifi access point? Also, ideally, is there a way to get it to switch to another wifi AP if I move closer to one of the other APs, and the signal gets better than the currently connected one?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by roaming with **wpa_supplicant**.

edit **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** adding the info of our APs assigning priorities to them.

For a wpa_suplicant based script able to associate to the strongest AP see i.e.

http://bashscripts.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=261

Comment: Good script, I had not seen it. Change *IWOPTS=-D wext* to *IWOPTS=-D nl80211* to use the newer driver.

Comment: Hrm... this is an 8 year old script. Does it play nicely with network manager?

Comment: see the examples of NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant working together i.e. https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse